Build env issue - .so files not getting packaged into APKs when using android prefabs, only on my machine
I am trying to build an android app but encountered an issue. When I try to use the openssl prefab for example, the openssl.so/libcrypto.so files do not get packed into the APK. This applies even to a brand new blank NDK project with nothing but the prefab. When I try to run the app, I get this
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.example.myapplication2, PID: 3723
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcrypto.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~ZiyE6_J10pUvMSnKs4xW4A==/com.example.myapplication2-z6zIpCtVD-xUDRzIzDQC6A==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/libmyapplication2.so in namespace clns-6
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1082)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
    at com.example.myapplication2.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

Upon examining the APK in android studio, it is clear those files did not make it in.
If I copy the test project onto another machine running the same OS, it works fine. I have tried reinstalling the SDK, android studio, and java. I've tried making new projects and clearing every cache I know of. I've tried everything I can think of short of reinstalling windows 11.
Additionally, if I manually build and package the library, that works too. Don't want to do that for just my machine tho. Want to use the prefab.
UPDATE:
I am losing my absolute mind here. Debug log from another machine:
2024-05-25T22:50:53.471+0500 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '[SNIP]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe'' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
2024-05-25T22:50:53.471+0500 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: Received process result: 0
2024-05-25T22:50:53.473+0500 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: check expected build outputs
2024-05-25T22:50:53.475+0500 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: hard linked [SNIP]\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\534a15e00cee7868133770eeb4ac1251\transformed\openssl-1.1.1q-beta-1\prefab\modules\crypto\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libcrypto.so to [SNIP]\Desktop\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\3359553c\obj\arm64-v8a\libcrypto.so
2024-05-25T22:50:53.477+0500 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: hard linked [SNIP]\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\534a15e00cee7868133770eeb4ac1251\transformed\openssl-1.1.1q-beta-1\prefab\modules\ssl\libs\android.arm64-v8a\libssl.so to [SNIP]\Desktop\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\3359553c\obj\arm64-v8a\libssl.so
2024-05-25T22:50:53.479+0500 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: hard linked [SNIP]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\libc++_shared.so to [SNIP]\Desktop\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\3359553c\obj\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so

Same step and same app on my machine
2024-05-25T10:28:59.487-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: SUCCEEDED
2024-05-25T10:28:59.487-0600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command '"C:\Users\Gradyn Wursten\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe"'' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
2024-05-25T10:28:59.487-0600 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: Received process result: 0
2024-05-25T10:28:59.488-0600 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: check expected build outputs
2024-05-25T10:28:59.490-0600 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: hard linked C:\Users\Gradyn Wursten\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\libc++_shared.so to C:\Users\Gradyn Wursten\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\3359553c\obj\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
2024-05-25T10:28:59.491-0600 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.IssueReporterLoggingEnvironment] C/C++: build complete

no errors. just getting skipped entirely. I made sure the gradle cache downloaded it, and it did.

Looks like this happens if there is a space in your windows username even if the SDK and project are not in your home directory.
